# how to update filter abi android in google playStore?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-console

I want to ask that I  config apk ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a' and update in google playStore.Does the Google Play app market allow such updates?thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can remove support for some ABIs in your app.

You then have the option to either carry over the last version of your app in the latest release (in addition to your new APK) as a "fallback support" so that users having these ABIs can still install an older version of your app. Or you can drop support entirely.